# Linux socket acting as Multicast Server and Client

Tags: c++, linux

I used two sockets in the same process, one acting as multicast server and the other acting as multicast client. I am trying to combine both server and client functionality in a single socket. Could not succeed till now. Did any one tried making a single socket as multicast server and client. Is it possible? If not any reference that states the limitation would be appreciated. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, at least on windows. Try following example(without error checking):

```
SOCKET the_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

sockaddr_in service;
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.117");
service.sin_port = htons(56565);

int ret = bind(the_socket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof (service));

unsigned int grpaddr = inet_addr("224.4.4.44");
unsigned int iaddr = inet_addr("192.168.1.117");

//You should have the equivalent function in your existing client 
//to join the multicast group
ret = join_source_group(the_socket, grpaddr, service.sin_addr.s_addr, iaddr);

std::string data = "AA";

sockaddr_in group;
group.sin_family = AF_INET;
group.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.4.4.44");
group.sin_port = htons(56565);

ret = sendto(the_socket, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0, (const sockaddr*)&group, sizeof(group));

char recvdata[3] = {0};
ret = recv(the_socket, recvdata, 3, 0);

leave_source_group(the_socket, grpaddr, service.sin_addr.s_addr, iaddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Server" and "Client" are not terms which really fit very comfortably into non connection-based sockets. Particularly with multicasting.

So a "Multicast receiver" and "Multicast sender" might be more appropriate.

You can of course, use the same socket to do both at once. It is not mandatory to join a group to send messages to it, but if you do, you may receive your own messages (in some OSs this is optional, for instancce using Linux's setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_LOOP).

"Server" and "client" are really concepts which work at a higher layer than multicasting. I hope that you can explain what you are trying to do better, maybe in another question.

Whether a multicast sender or receiver is the client or server, depends entirely on the application.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. They make sense. I do mean multicast receiver and sender functionality on the same socket.